# Implementing stub function and linking it to a definition in a library during run time

Tags: windows, visual-c++, clang, shared-libraries

When I was reading about using shared libraries, I learnt how the definitions of standard C functions, like printf, are resolved during run-time.
I want to implement functions in my project in the similar manner. I can have stub definition of functions for compiling and linking phase. And actual definition of the functions will be present in a library on the device where I'll run my executable.

Suppose I have a main function:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include"sum.h"
int main()
{
    int num = 10;
    int result = 0;
    result = sum(num);
    printf("Sum = %d\n",result);
    return 0;
}
```

And my sum.h looks like:

```
#ifndef SUM_H
#define SUM_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#ifndef __EXPORT
#ifdef _USERDLL
#define __EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define __EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif // _USER_DLL
#endif // __EXPORT

__EXPORT int sum(int num);
}
#endif
#endif
```

And while builiding this executable, I'll use stub definition in sum_stub.c file:

```
// sum_stub.c
#include<stdio.h>
#include"sum.h"
int sum(int num) {
    int res = 0;
    printf("Inside stubbed function. Result=%d\n",res);
    return res;
}
```

Let the executable that is build using above files is get_sum.exe

The actual function that will calculate sum is compiled as a shared library, say sum.dll.

```
// sum.c that will be compiled to sum.dll
#include<stdio.h>
#include"sum.h"
int sum(int num) {
    int res = 0;
    int i=0;
    for (i=0; i<num; i++)
        res = res + i;
    return res;
}
```

Now as I run my executable, get_sum.exe, how can I link sum.dll at runtime so that correct function definition is used (inside sum.dll) instead of the stubbed one, that I used while compiling the executable?
I am looking for a way to implement it on windows target machine i.e. by using MSVC build tools and clang compiler.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called "Delay-loaded DLL". Details on overriding default DLL loading code are provided in [MSDN article on Linker support for delay-loaded DLLs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linker-support-for-delay-loaded-dlls?view=msvc-160).